# Will vim .bashrc command create new bashrc file? How can I remove them?

Tags: linux, bash

I used `vim .bashrc` to open my bashrc file, but I forgot to go to the home directory. I think this command have created several new bashrc files, should I remove those files?

Comment: You already have an answer, but my tip is to use `vim ~/.bashrc` so you don't have to bother about which folder you reside in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having multiple `.bashrc` files in different locations will not cause any issues. The one in your home directory is the only one that is loaded when you launch bash. You may want to delete them however to avoid confusion if others use your system/server.

You can use `rm .bashrc` after you have changed directory to the directory containing the `.bashrc` you accidentally created using `cd <location of extra .bashrc>`.

Note: Vim will not create a file unless you exit with `:wq`.